# Infinite login loop when using adal.js 1.0.14

Tags: javascript, adal.js

I'm encountering an infinite login loop with adal.js 1.0.14. **I'm NOT using angular**, but my application is a SPA. The issue occurs in Chrome and Edge.

#### Repro steps

1. Visit my SPA in Incognito Mode to ensure clean state
2. Create authentication context and invoke handleWindowCallback()
3. Application prompts me to login since `getCachedToken(myClientId)` is null
4. Redirected to AAD login page
5. Redirected back to site after successful login
6. Create authentication context and invoke `handleWindowCallback()`
7. Logged in successfully, all is well...
8. Wait for the `id_token` to expire (i was simulating this by setting the time to 0 in localStorage)
9. Refresh the SPA via browser's refresh button
10. Create authentication context and invoke `handleWindowCallback()`
11. Application prompts me to login since `getCachedToken(myClientId)` is null
12. Redirected to AAD login page
13. Redirected back to site after successful login
14. Steps 10-13 repeat infinitely from here on

With the debugger stepping through `handleWindowCallback()` of step 10, I see adal.login.error gets set to "`Nonce is not same as undefined`" within `saveTokenFromHash` of adal.js code.

#### adal.js verbose logging

Here's what is present in the console at step 11:

```
authenticator.js:26 Fri, 21 Jul 2017 05:37:50 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: State: 84c5d552-3f24-4f7f-a871-71e67f8d6482
authenticator.js:26 Fri, 21 Jul 2017 05:37:50 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: Returned from redirect url
authenticator.js:26 Fri, 21 Jul 2017 05:37:51 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: State status:true; Request type:LOGIN
authenticator.js:26 Fri, 21 Jul 2017 05:37:51 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: State is right
authenticator.js:26 Fri, 21 Jul 2017 05:37:51 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: Fragment has id token
```

#### adal configuration

```
{
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    clientId: 'my applicationId goes in here...',
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    tenant: 'microsoft.onmicrosoft.com'
}
```

#### Code

This code is executed upfront when loading my SPA (repro steps 1-3 and 9-11 in other words).

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(configuration);

authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();

if (!authenticationContext.getCachedToken(authenticationContext.config.clientId)) {
    authenticationContext.login();
}
```

#### What have I tried?

- I'd like to avoid clearing the cache before invoking login. As I understand it, this will work around the issue, but is not desirable.
- This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/216) suggested adding `anonymousEndpoints = []` to adal config, but this did not help.

Let me know if more details are needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more debugging, I have resolved my specific issue.

Due to the nature of Javascript, code after `authenticationContext.login()` is executed. Calling `login()` will navigate the application to AAD sign-in page, but until navigation occurs, my code was still executing unexpectedly. I incorrectly assumed once `login()` was invoked, my code was done running and it was in ADAL's hands.

My *unconfirmed* hunch is that state was being clobbered by calling `acquireToken(authenticationContext.config.clientId)` immediately after `login()`, which manifested in `Nonce is not same as undefined` to appear as the error.

I say *unconfirmed* because I wasn't able debug into what exact state caused the issue. However, I changed my code path to not invoke `acquireToken` immediately after `login()` and the issue no longer occurred.

Fei's answer helped me isolate my issue, so thank you! In the spirit of sharing my resulting, functional code for the benefit of others, I adapted Fei's sample. Essentially, I wanted to renew tokens after they expire, so I setup an interval to invoke `acquireToken` every 20 seconds, but not immediately after application startup (when `login()` is likely to occur).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js\adal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var configuration = {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        clientId: 'my client id',
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        tenant: 'mytenant.onmicrosoft.com'
    }

    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(configuration);

    authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();

    if (!authenticationContext.getCachedToken(authenticationContext.config.clientId)) {
        authenticationContext.login();
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        authenticationContext.acquireToken(authenticationContext.config.clientId, function (errorDescription, token, error) {
            // do callback stuff...
        });
    }, 20000);

    function login() {
        authenticationContext.login();
    }
    </script>

    <div>
        <button id="button1" onclick="login()">Login</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to reproduce this issue using the adal.js with version `1.0.14` however failed. To check whether this is a code issue, I am appending the code demo which I am testing:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js\adal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var configuration = {
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            clientId: 'eca61fd9-f491-4f03-a622-90837bbc1711',
            instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
            tenant: 'adfei.onmicrosoft.com'
        }

        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(configuration);

        authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();

        if (!authenticationContext.getCachedToken(authenticationContext.config.clientId)) {
            authenticationContext.login();
        }

        function login(){
            authenticationContext.login();
        }
    </script>

    <div>
    <button id="button1" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

The app acquire the token successfully after I set `adal.expiration.key{clientId}` with 0.